# jQuery 2.0.x How to 'roll-you-own' limited version

Tags: jquery

I am interested in selecting a subset of jQuery's SRC files to build a smaller "limited scope" version.  I am looking for some additional focused information on "dependencies" and/or any suggestions.  For example, I do need some ajax, say "jsonp."  Do I need .../src/ajax.js and ...src/ajax/jsonp.js but not script.js and not xhr.js. Of course that is a simple example but is there a "map" perhaps of some common combinations to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [How to build your own jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/README.md)

> The grunt build process is aware of dependencies across modules. If you explicitly remove a module, its dependent modules will be removed as well. For example, excluding the css module also excludes effects, since the effects module uses .css() to animate CSS properties. These dependencies are listed in Gruntfile.js and the build process shows a message for each dependent module it excludes.